# Flutter showModalBottomSheet is hidden behind CupertinoTabBar

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, flutter-cupertino, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, cupertinotabbar

I use CupertinoTabBar, but want to show material design BottomSheet when user's device is Android.
However, when I used both of them, BottomSheet is hidden behind CupertinoTabBar like below.

Could you help me to fix this? Or is it bad to use both of them?

[image]

#### My simplified code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void onPressed(BuildContext context) async {
    await showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Delete'),
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('delete'),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Cancel'),
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('cancel'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CupertinoTabScaffold(
        tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.music_note),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            ),
          ]
        ),
        tabBuilder: (context, index) {
          switch (index) {
            case 0:
              return CupertinoTabView(
                builder: (context) {
                  return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text('button'),
                      onPressed: () => onPressed(context),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            case 1:
              return CupertinoTabView(
                builder: (context) {
                  return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                    child: Text('tab 2'),
                  );
                },
              );
          }
          return Container();
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer, is it okay for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to set `useRootNavigator` to `true`. This will display model sheet above all other content.

> The useRootNavigator parameter ensures that the root navigator is used to display the bottom sheet when set to true. This is useful in the case that a modal bottom sheet needs to be displayed above all other content but the caller is inside another Navigator.

Refactored code:

```
    void onPressed(BuildContext context) async {
     await showModalBottomSheet(
      useRootNavigator: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Delete'),
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('delete'),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Cancel'),
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('cancel'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set some padding below or set container height for this. I edit your code setting some padding, please check it.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void onPressed(BuildContext context) async {
    await showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Padding(
        padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 60),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Delete'),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('delete'),
            ),
            Divider(),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Cancel'),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('cancel'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: CupertinoTabScaffold(
            tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.music_note),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              ),
            ]),
            tabBuilder: (context, index) {
              switch (index) {
                case 0:
                  return CupertinoTabView(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                        child: FlatButton(
                          child: Text('button'),
                          onPressed: () => onPressed(context),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                case 1:
                  return CupertinoTabView(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                        child: Text('tab 2'),
                      );
                    },
                  );
              }
              return Container();
            }));
  }
}
```